# Apply Series function to the whole dataframe

Tags: pandas

Well, I knew that function on each" cell" can applies to the whole dataframe using applymap()
However, is there any way to apply Series function,eg: str.upper() to the whole dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could be applied directly to the [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) method of the dataframe.

***Demo:***

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']])
df
```

[image]

---

Various possiblities:

1) `applymap` dataframe:

```
df.applymap(str.upper)
```

2) `stack` + `unstack` combo:

```
df.stack().str.upper().unstack()
```

3) `apply` series:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.upper())
```

All produce:

[image]

Comment: Tks a lot for ur answer. It worked. But why u remove the parentheses ()

Comment: `apply` and `applymap` accept functions as their arguments.  He is passing the function `str.upper` that will then be applied to every cell

Comment: Yes, we can directly pass function calls to this method. If you insist on using parenthesis, `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.upper())` would also work but with `apply` instead.

Comment: Tks, It seems to make more sense to me !